Why are my Link components breaking the react app?
I'm trying to display some components based on the URL using createBrowserRouter but when I include the Link components my app just stops working. The clients, orders and products components are just h2s btw.
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <aside className="sidebar col-3">
      <h2>Management</h2>
      <nav className="nav">
        <Link to="/" className="clients">
          Clients
        </Link>
        <Link to="/products" className="products">
          Products
        </Link>
        <Link to="/orders" className="orders">
          Orders
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  );
}

import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Clients from "./components/clients/Clients.jsx";
import Header from "./components/layout/Header.jsx";
import Nav from "./components/layout/Nav.jsx";
import Orders from "./components/orders/Orders.jsx";
import Products from "./components/products/Products.jsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <Clients /> },
  { path: "/products", element: <Products /> },
  { path: "/orders", element: <Orders /> },
]);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="grid container main-content">
        <Nav />
        <main className="content-box col-9">
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

These are the errors I'm getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of
'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null. Consider adding an error
boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.


your router is nested too deep - the nav component needs it
